# A merchant with geometric progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A merchant bought a quantity of cotton; this he exchanged for oil which he sold.He observed that the number of 'kg' of cotton,the number of liters of oil obtained for each 'kg' and the number of rupees for which he sold formed a decreasing geometric progression.He calculated that if he had obtained 1 'kg' more of cotton,1 liter more of oil for each 'kg' and one rupee more for each liter, he would have obtained Rs.10169(Rs-rupees) more, whereas if he had obtained one 'kg' less of cotton and one liter less of oil for  each 'kg' and one rupee less for each liter, he would have obtained Rs.9673 less.How much he actually received(in rupees)?

Comment: What have you already deduced from the text and tried ?

Comment: to be frank I first of all did not clearly understand the question.I saw the question in the question paper and I proposed it.I worked out for some time and then gave up

Comment: sorry it is an examination and the examiner took all the papers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the number of 'Kg' of cotton he has, $b$ the number of 'liters' of oil he gets for a 'Kg' of cotton, and $c$ the number of 'Rs' he gets by selling one 'liter' of oil.

His profit is thus $a\cdot b\cdot c$

Then, the text tells us that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=abc+10169$ and that $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=abc-9673$

What is more, $a,b,c$ are in geometric progression hence $b^2=ac$

The two first equations give us 
$(bc + ab + ca) + (a + b + c) = 10168$ and $(bc + ab + ac) – (a + b + c) = 9672$, which by adding/subtracting leads us to :

$bc + ab + ca = 9920\Leftrightarrow bc + ab + b^2= 9920\Leftrightarrow b(a+b+c) = 9920$

and $a+b+c = 248$

Hence $b=40,ac=1600,a+c=208$ thus $a=200$ and $c=8$

**His profit was thus $abc=Rs.6400$**

Comment: what are x,y,z?

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula That was a typo, it's $a,b,c$

Comment: how to solve these equations and what to do next

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula Why don't you try by yourself before ? It has been less than 4 mins since you got that answer with the typo fixed ...

Comment: As I  have told you that i did not understand the question clearly i don't understand what to find i did not understand the sentence 'how much he actually received'so i am requesting you to give the full answer

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula Done

Comment: again what are these x,y,z

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula Stupid typo, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: hey who is stupid  i think you did not fix it properly i can still see some x,y,z in the fourth and fifth lines

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula 'stupid' was referring to my error, not to you ... Anyway, fixed the last remaining xyz

Comment: thank you, you have made me understand the problem and gave the answer sorry, in case if i have troubled you

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula If your problem is answered, you can upvote the answer and click the 'accept' button :)

Comment: it is done and the answer is very explanatory